# Python/SQL error, where the error doesn't register

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

So I am self teaching sqlite3 and and python simultaneously and I am having a problem, but getting no errors so I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. 
When I run the program, everything seems to work great. It asks my questions, accepts the input, and ends the connection to the database.

The problem comes when I go back and check the data in the table, and nothing has been updated. I assume the issue is with my UPDATE sql execute but I can't find the error.

```
import sqlite3 #import the sqlite3 library
conn = sqlite3.connect('trailer.db') ##establish connection to the database
c = conn.cursor() ##set var c to connected cursor

def path():
  user_selection = input("Are you changing a trailer status(1) or updating driver info(2)")
  if user_selection == "1":
    update_trailer()
  else:
    update_driver()


def update_trailer():
  n = int ( input("Enter the trailer number: "))
  l = input ("Where is the trailer located: ")
  s = input ("What is the current trailer status: ")


  updated_data = "UPDATE data SET location = ?, status = ? WHERE id = ?" 
  utd = (l, s, n)
  c.execute(updated_data, utd)
  conn.commit()
  conn.close()

#def update_driver():
 # n2 = int ( input ("Which trailer are we updating? "))
 #c = input ("Where was the gas used or filled? ")
 # d = input ("Which driver is picking  up the trailer? ") 
 # des = input ("Where is the trailer destination? ")


path()
```

(Ignore the update_driver section, its a work in progress)

Comment: Are you sure there _is_ a matching row for that `id`?

Comment: your code is working for me, you should check your db location and matching the columns in correct order.

Comment: Are you maybe expecting the `update` statement to insert a new row in the table if there isn't one with a matching id there already?

Answer (score 0):

Man I feel dumb. I had a previous python script for entering the trailers into the database, and then was working on a separate .py page to update said trailers and was using one data entry that I hadn't previously entered.  Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer : Code worked, user error. Must update an ID that is already INSERTED into the DB.